# Charset and fonts shown by `describe-char`

Tags: fonts, character-encoding, unicode, japanese

I have some questions about emacs internal actions related to charset and fonts shown by `describe-char`.

Now I use `utf-8` as character encording scheme (CES) on emacs, so charsets shown by `describe-char` are supposed to "unicode". But since I often use Japanese kanji, the following configuration

```
(set-language-environment "Japanese")
```

is added. Then charset of kanjis is changed to "japanese-jisx0208" keeping CES to be `utf-8` like the below (ex.kanji "字").

```
             position: 813 of 2102 (39%), column: 51
            character: 字 (displayed as 字) (codepoint 23383, #o55527, #x5b57)
    preferred charset: japanese-jisx0208 (JISX0208.1983/1990 Japanese Kanji: ISO-IR-87)
code point in charset: 0x3B7A
               script: han
               syntax: w    which means: word
             category: .:Base, C:2-byte han, L:Left-to-right (strong), c:Chinese, h:Korean, j:Japanese, |:line breakable
             to input: type "C-x 8 RET 5b57"
          buffer code: #xE5 #xAD #x97
            file code: #xE5 #xAD #x97 (encoded by coding system utf-8-unix)
              display: by this font (glyph code)
    xft:-VL  -VL Gothic-normal-normal-normal-*-18-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1 (#x15A9)

Character code properties: customize what to show
  name: CJK IDEOGRAPH-5B57
  general-category: Lo (Letter, Other)
  decomposition: (23383) ('字')
```

I considered `utf-8` transforms characters of Unicode to byte codes not "japanese-jisx0208", but the shown charset is "japanese-jisx0208". So I have following two questions.

1. Setting language environment of emacs "Japanese", is the encording with `utf-8` executed after the shwon charset "japanese-jisx0208" is transformed to "unicode" inside emacs?
2. Depending on my first question, why the font of unicode (`-VL Gothic-normal-normal-normal-*-18-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1`) is applied?